# Assigning InheritedWidget in build-Method

Tags: flutter, dart, inherited-widget

Let A be an InheritedWidget, that I can get throughout the whole app by calling A.of(context).

If I have a StatefulWidget, what is the better option (in terms of performance or code quality):

A)

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  
  A a;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    a ??= A.of(context);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

B)

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final a = A.of(context);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I have never seen someone using Option A), so I am wondering. I prefer Option A) because every method in the _TestState class can use the a-Object easily and it is also assigned only once in the build method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B is likely enough if you keep widgets small. It won't be great if you have many methods that depend on the inherited widget.

Reading option A brings up questions in my mind like

- "You're caching `A`, do you care if `A` changes up in the tree?"
- "Is `A` needed outside of build?"

  - "If so, why? Do we know it will be initialized at that point?"
  - "If not, why is it an instance field?"

Both options work though.

In terms of code quality a third option is to apply the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) by making `A` a parameter to the widget.

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({@required this.a});
  final A a;
  ...
}
```

Then callers can create it with `MyStatefulWidget(a: A.of(context))`. This reads better than option A, though, granted, they're not equivalent.

I'm not aware of performance differences considerable enough to discuss here.

Comment: `A` is used throughout the entire app. Accessing it by A.of(context) in every build method where I need it, seemed to be better solution than taking `A` as a parameter for every widget constructor in the tree.
For readability reasons, some widgets I need in a screen are built outside the build method. So it seemed to be a better solution, that every single method in my StatefulWidget has access to `A`, so again I don't have to take `A` as a parameter for the sub widgets again. Instead of calling buildSpecificWidget(`A` a), I call buildSpecificWidget() inside the build method.